# Triple XoR - Find relation between the numbers.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have

> > a = b^c;
> >
> > b = a^c;

Is it possible to eliminate `c` and find a relation between a and b? I have 3 different `a` values and would like to find the values of corresponding `b`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two equations stated in the problem are redundant because of these properties of xor:

(i) xor is commutative and associative;

(ii) $y \mbox{ xor } y=0$ for all $y$.

(iii) $y \mbox{ xor } 0 = y$ for all $y$.

Thus the second equation can be obtained from the first by xor-ing both sides of the first equation by $c$.  Similarly, if you xor the second equation by $c$, you get the first.

So  in effect you only have one equation; and you cannot eliminate $c$. (Any two of the values can be arbitrary; but then the third is determined.)